# Replication-Replication Distribution Subsystem: agent initialization failed. The publication (publication name)does not exist. Error: 14173,sevirity18

Tags: transactional-replication

In SQL logs, we are getting above replication warning messages continuously for every around 30 seconds for few publications but from these one deleted earlier but other three publications are still available, running and replicating the data into subscriber. But here the issue is that we are getting above errors in SQL logs continuously for all four (even for deleted publications and active publications also) but we are not able to find the reason for that.

Kindly help us to troubleshoot the issue. Thanks a lot in advance.